# SequelizeUniqueConstraintError on bulkcreate with association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

**when calling bulkCreate on model with option ignoreDuplicates: true, only main query is INSERT OR IGNORE, any association query is INSERT only.**

details:

I have 2 models:

```
class Article extends Model {}
Article.init(
    {
        comments: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
    { sequelize, modelName: "article" }
);

Article.hasOne(Product);
```

and

```
class Product extends Model {}
Product.init(
    {
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
    { sequelize, modelName: "product" }
);
```

then I call

```
Article.bulkCreate(payload, {
    ignoreDuplicates: true,
    include: [Product]
});
```

sequelize creates 2 insert queries, first:
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO articles ...
but second is:
    INSERT INTO products

is there any way to force ignoreDuplicates option on second query? I tried many things, I feel like my only option is to split payload to separate objects and create 2 bulkCreate functions.

Comment: Add an association on Product.belongsTo ...

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried it, but it did not help. sequelize still trying to INSERT INTO products.